# Custom Ubuntu Installation Error

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

I built an OS installer with pinguy builder. Upon installation of this custom Ubuntu OS, the installer threw an error and got stuck at these error messages:

```
insanityos apt-setup: Source list entries for this disc are:
insanityos apt-setup: deb cdrom:[InsanityOS 18.04 - Release amd64]/ dists/
insanityos apt-setup: Repeat this process for the rest of the CDs in your set.
insanityos in-target: Ign:1 cdrom://InsanityOS 18.04 - Release amd64 dists/ InRelease
insanityos in-target: Err:2 cdrom://InsanityOS 18.04 - Release amd64 dists/ Release
insanityos in-target:   Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognied by APT, apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
```

How do I fix these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Simply run `add-apt-repository` with the `-r` flag and the line representing the repo, from your output

> ... apt-setup: deb cdrom:[InsanityOS 18.04 - Release amd64]/ dists/

You can see the line itself.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb cdrom:[InsanityOS 18.04 - Release amd64]/ dists/'
```

Or edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove or comment out the corresponding line for the cdrom.

Comment: Unforuantely it isn't in the file /etc/apt/sources.list